# Javascript used in rails with webpacker doesn't give any console.log output

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this code in `application.js`

```
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")

import start from './games/chatcher'

console.log(1)

export {
    start
}
```

but i don't get any output in console

Why?

Edit:
my webpacker related lines in `package.json`

```
{
    "@rails/webpacker": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpacker-cli": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
 }
```

and my `Gemfile`

`gem 'webpacker', '~> 6.x'`

I assume that it could be because I updated webpacker and probably some versions don't work correct.

Comment: It’s likely that line is not executed. Are you sure that script successfully compiled and is included on the page?

Comment: @rossta, are there any ways how to check that?

Comment: Check the page source, see if it includes `application.js`. You can follow the link to the file and see if your code is included.

Comment: @Anuj, yes I have this line `<script src="/packs/js/application-ea50d33bb2592656d381.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>`

Comment: What version of the Webpacker gem and NPM package are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in a turbolinks:load listener:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  console.log(1)
}
```

You can also check if webpack is compiling correctly by running `bin/webpack` in your terminal.

Comment: I'll do it, but I never had to. It always worked from the box. Could it be because I yesterday updated webpack and webpacker gem?

Comment: Nope, still output is none.  Moreover, if I look in firefox's debugger and ckeck compiled file there are this 
`document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function () {
  console.log(1);
});`
Rails is making me mad

Comment: It does that to everyone until you fix it. It's really a love-hate relationship.

Comment: Possibly webpacker issue. What's your webpacker lines in Gemfile and pacage.json?

Comment: `Gemfile` : `gem 'webpacker', '~> 6.x'`
`package.json` : `webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpacker-cli": "^2.2.1"
` and these are devs: 
`"version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
`